# Invalid column count in CSV input

Tags: php, csv, phpmyadmin, localhost

I'm trying to insert a ".csv" file into a SQL database with phpMyAdmin. However, every time I import it, I get the error: Invalid column count in CSV input on row 1. I've spent all day playing around with various options to try and get it working but to no avail. my columns contain long text (Twitter crawl results) There are exactly 2 columns in my .csv file.Type format using longtext. If I change the format from CSV to CV using load data, only the second column is read. please help. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[this is my csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49kJS.png)

Comment: "There are exactly 3 columns in my .csv" - looking at the screenshot I'm only seeing two columns?

Comment: sorry, I mean 2 columns, but I added column id (auto incremenct) in phpmyadmin

Comment: do attach some of that csv data as plain text to your description - that is more helpful in finding the issue